# SoftEther is extemely slow

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, vpn

I have followed [these instructions](https://miff2000.github.io/blog/2017/05/18/softether-multi-protocol-vpn-server.html) to install SoftEther on Ubuntu 18. It is a droplet from DigitalOcean. Client is Windows 10 PC and Android phone (SSTP).

Without connecting to VPN my throughput is around 14 Mbps. After connecting it is barely 1 Mbps. The clients are connected to ADSL modem. I am not behind any firewall or NAT.

I have no idea where to look and how to solve this issue.

EDIT:

While it is obvious to me that the download speed is very different with and without VPN, I have also used Internet Download Manager to confirm it.

The droplet is Ubuntu 18.04.3, 2GB RAM. The graphs show that the CPU usage has never reached above %6.6 and the output of TOP command shows that "vpnserver" is utilizing around %3 CPU and %2.5 RAM.

I have a paid VPN account too. The provider is using SoftEther as server and I have no issue at all when connected to it (both SSTP and SoftEther client) so I guess the problem is not on my side.

Comment: How did you test the bandwidth? What kind of Droplet did you set up?

Comment: I have updated my post with more info. Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the SecureNAT feature.  The softether manual literally warns you against using it, as the overhead is substantial, given that they are essentially creating an entire internal tcp/ip virtual network stack in software.  See "Precautions relating to Performance"